# updateListitems issue

Tags: spservices, updatelistitems

I want to update SharePoint survey answers using `spservices` so I used `UpdateListItems` to update this

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: params.sp_content.base_url,
    batchCmd: "Update",
    listName: "{17C2EC72-7229-445D-87A1-38AE11051906}",
    ID:3,
    valuepairs: [["What_x0020_is_x0020_your_x0020_n", titletest]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        alert("completed-" + Status + xData);
    }
});
```

and ID here is `UniqueID` from the response

but in Status return `"parseerror"` and `responseText` return

```
{"IsSucceeded":false,"error_code":1,"error_msg":"The file \u0027/mobile/sharepoint.emeint.net/test.emeint.net/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx\u0027 does not exist.","error_details":0,"more_details":null,"expiration":{"is_allowed":false,"duration":0,"method":0,"mode":0,"is_session_expiry":false},"persistence":{"scope":0,"is_encrypted":false},"total_seconds":0,"data":null}"
```

Comment: As Marc response stated in the forum thread, your URL is likely the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you are providing listID instead of List Name and could be the source of the issue

```
listName: "{17C2EC72-7229-445D-87A1-38AE11051906}", //give list name here
```

Comment: Thank You for your response, but I use listName this way before while getting list item using (GetListItem ) in spservice and it works or if you have any suggestion please tell me

Comment: did you try with list name?